# Replace bitbake task with bbappend

Tags: yocto, bitbake, meta-raspberrypi

The task do_kernel_configme is defined in yocto base layers and added to by meta-raspberrypi. How do I override only the parts added by meta-raspberrypi using a bbappend file?

Current setup is something like:

```
meta-mylayer          rpi-recipe.bbappend   do_kernel_configme_prepend()
meta-raspberrypi      rpi-recipe.bb         do_kernel_configme_prepend()
<yocto base layers>   some-recipe.bb        do_kernel_configme()
```

When I run this, both additions are prepended which means the "mylayer" code is run first, then meta-raspberrypi, then base.

How do I completely override the meta-raspberrypi additions so only the "mylayer" code followed by base layer code is executed.

(The same question also applies to do_configure task.)

Comment: I don't think there is any mechanism to do that. Probably there is some other way to achieve your goals if you can tell what is the problem with prepend from meta-raspberrypi.

Comment: I'm trying to add a custom kernel defconfig but it is overwitten by meta-raspberrypi configme.

Comment: Well, you can just install your config into `${S}/arch/${ARCH}/configs/${KERNEL_DEFCONFIG}` and then let meta-raspberrypi take it from there as it's the only thing it does from what I see. Not elegant, certainly, but something that will work. As a thought, also --- what are the priorities of `meta-mylayer` and `meta-raspberrypi`, maybe playing with them will change the order of prepends.

Comment: Well, I was trying to avoid installing into `${S]/arch/...` but its the solution I'll use for now.

Comment: Add your defconfig to your layer and add a "bbappend" with FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend.